# RDP losing connection to Printer

Tags: batch-file, rdp, printers

Is there a way to restablish the connection with remote printer via cmd(without restarting spooler)?

I work at a company whose clients use an RDP acess to a server. They use a local printer to do the job.

The problem is that when the connection oscilates, they often can't see their printer anymore. The only way to see them again is to logoff the user, then log in again.

I use .bat files a lot, but couldn't find anything related to that.

Ps: restarting the spooler is not an option, since this would affect other users.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try a look at `net use ...` or `net share`

Answer (score -2):

Hmmm, 
After a bit of thought, you could simply install Chrome on a local client machine and the RDP server to make use of Google cloud print which is quite resilient. Another potential application of meta-programming.